# Dealing with little o(1) term in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

I am trying to follow a line in a paper. I will just copy it in here:

(All quantities, i.e. $H,q$ and $\tau$, are functions of $t$.)

> As $\tau\to\infty$ we have $q=\frac{1}{2}+o(1)$. Now $dH/dt=-(1+q)H^2$. It follows that $H=\frac{2}{3}t^{-1}(1+o(1))$.

Why does that follow? I can see that truncating the $o(1)$ term, such that $q\approx1/2$ would yield $H\approx\frac{2}{3}t^{-1}$, i.e. the first term of the result.

I however have difficulties to understand why taking the $o(1)$ term in the ODE into account yields precisely this $o(1)$ term in the result after integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the same $o(1)$ term. $o(1)$ represents a function $f$ satisfying $f(\tau)\to 0$ as $\tau\to\infty$, but the function $f$ can change between different instances of the notation $o(1)$. So what the statement means is that $H$ is given as $H(t) = \frac{2}{3}t^{-1} + \frac{2}{3}t^{-1}h(t)$, where $h(t)$ is $o(1)$ as $\tau\to\infty$. Here there is some abuse of notation: we really mean $h(t(\tau))\to 0$ as $\tau\to\infty$; presumably $t$ can also be written as a function of $\tau$. So you'll want to determine this function $h$ (presumably by solving equation, which is separable) and show that it has this asymptotic behavior.

A more detailed answer:

Write $q(t) = \frac{1}{2} + h(t)$, where $h$ is some function satisfying $h(t) = o(1)$ as $\tau\to\infty$. The specific form of $h$ turns out not to matter.

The equation is separable, and solving the initial value problem with initial value specified at $t=0$, we obtain
$$
H(t) = \left(\frac{3t}{2} + \int_0^t h(s)~ds + \frac{1}{H(0)}\right)^{-1}.
$$
We factor out a $\frac{2}{3t}$ from each term, obtaining
$$
H(t) = \frac{2}{3t}\left(1 + \frac{2}{3t}\int_0^t h~ds + \frac{2}{3t}\frac{1}{H(0)}\right)^{-1}.
$$
We wish to show that the right-hand side is $\frac{2}{3t}(1+o(1))$. To see this, we write
$$
\left(1 + \frac{2}{3t}\int_0^t h~ds + \frac{2}{3t}\frac{1}{H(0)}\right)^{-1} = 1 - \frac{\frac{2}{3t}\int_0^t h~ds + \frac{2}{3t}\frac{1}{H(0)}}{1 + \frac{2}{3t}\int_0^t h~ds + \frac{2}{3t}\frac{1}{H(0)}} = 1 + f(t).
$$
We claim that $f(t)$ is $o(1)$ as $t\to\infty$; you haven't provided this detail, but I presume $\tau$ is defined so that $t\to\infty$ if and only if $\tau\to\infty$ in this problem. We simply need to see that $f(t)\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$. To do this we bound each term in the fraction. Since $h(t)\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$, for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $T>0$ so that $|h(t)|<\varepsilon$ for $t>T$. Then
$$
\frac{2}{3t}\int_0^t |h(s)|~ds \leq \frac{2}{3t}\int_0^T |h(s)|~ds + \frac{2}{3t}\int_T^t \varepsilon~ds  \leq \frac{2}{3t}\int_0^T |h(s)|~ds + \frac{2\varepsilon}{3}\frac{t-T}{t}.
$$
In the right-most expression, the second term is bounded by $C\varepsilon$ as $t\to\infty$, where $C$ is some constant independent of $t$. The first term is bounded by $\frac{1}{t}$ times a constant (in $t$). So for any $\varepsilon$, letting $t\to\infty$ we find that 
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{2}{3t}\int_0^t |h(s)|~ds \leq C\varepsilon.
$$
Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary it follows that
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{2}{3t}\int_0^t h(s)~ds = 0.
$$
As for $\frac{1}{t}\frac{1}{H(0)}$, obviously this tends to $0$ as $t\to\infty$. Therefore taking limits, we find that
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t) =  -\frac{\lim_{t\to\infty}(\frac{2}{3t}\int_0^t h~ds + \frac{2}{3t}\frac{1}{H(0)})}{\lim_{t\to\infty}(1 + \frac{2}{3t}\int_0^t h~ds + \frac{2}{3t}\frac{1}{H(0)})} = \frac{0}{1} = 0.
$$
Therefore $f(t) = o(1)$ as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for help! I am not sure if I can follow. I understand the final statement as such. What I do not see is, why the final statement follows from the two sentences before.

Comment: Or let me ask differently: Does the final statement require the knowledge of the concrete o(1) function in the first sentence, or is it true regardless how that function looks in detail, as long as it is o(1)?

Comment: @Britzel The specific form of the $o(1)$ function does not matter; see the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for this effort! I can follow and understand now. Thanks a lot!